# Getting error "Cannot understand Bad formula! 'Starting From' " while sending following XML request to Tally to get the list of companies on disk

Tags: tally

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
        <ID>CA_COMPANY</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:xml</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <REPORT ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_COMPANY">
                        <FORM>CA_COMPANY</FORM>
                    </REPORT>
                    <FORM ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_COMPANY">
                        <PART>CA_COMPANY</PART>
                        <XMLTAG>COMPANIES</XMLTAG>
                    </FORM>
                    <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_COMPANY">
                        <LINE>CA_COMPANY</LINE>
                        <REPEAT>CA_COMPANY:CA_COMPANYCOLLECTION</REPEAT>
                        <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                    </PART>
                    <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO"
                        NAME="CA_COMPANY">
                        <FIELDS>
                            CA_NAME,CA_STARTINGFROM
                        </FIELDS>
                        <XMLTAG>COMPANY</XMLTAG>
                    </LINE>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_NAME">
                        <SET>$NAME</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>NAME</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_STARTINGFROM">
                        <TYPE>Date</TYPE>
                        <SET>$STARTINGFROM</SET>
                        <XMLTAG>STARTINGFROM</XMLTAG>
                    </FIELD>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO"
                        ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="CA_COMPANYCOLLECTION">
                        <TYPE>COMPANYONDISK</TYPE>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>NAME</NATIVEMETHOD>
                        <NATIVEMETHOD>STARTINGFROM</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    </COLLECTION>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Getting error "Cannot understand Bad formula! 'Starting From' " while sending following XML request to Tally to get the list of companies on disk.
I am getting the desired result if I remove Starting Date, but I need starting date for my business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the exact Reason

but changing CA_STARTINGFROM fields xml tag to some other like StartingDate
(other than STARTINGFROM) worked.

Comment: But what would be the reason? because Name tag is working but neither StartingFrom nor EndingAt are working? Are these some sort of reserved keywords or something?

Comment: Don't know the exact reason.
they are methods in collection, but we can use them as we used Name.
but due to some Uknown reason we are getting bad formulae

Comment: sad that tally has a fake programming language and does not allow one to attach a real debugger without hacking. Things like this are easily solvable by step debugging

Comment: Yeah, having no native debugging facility is the main reason., I won't work on TDL projects,
Do you know how to attach debugger by hacking !